# String concatenation queries

Tags: string, algorithm

I have a list of characters, say x in number, denoted by `b[1], b[2], b[3] ... b[x]`. After `x`,

- `b[x+1]` is the concatenation of `b[1],b[2].... b[x]` in that order. Similarly,
- `b[x+2]` is the concatenation of `b[2],b[3]....b[x],b[x+1]`.
- So, basically, `b[n]` will be concatenation of last `x` terms of `b[i]`, taken left from right.
- Given parameters as `p` and `q` as queries, how can I find out which character among `b[1], b[2], b[3]..... b[x]` does the `q`<sup>th</sup> character of `b[p]` corresponds to?

**Note:** `x` and `b[1], b[2], b[3]..... b[x]` is fixed for all queries.

I tried brute-forcing but the string length increases exponentially for large x.(x<=100).

---

**Example:**

- When `x=3`,

  ```
  b[] = a, b, c, a b c, b c abc, c abc bcabc, abc bcabc cabcbcabc, //....  
  //Spaces for clarity, only commas separate array elements
  ```
- So for a query where `p=7`, `q=5`, answer returned would be `3`(corresponding to character `'c'`).

I am just having difficulty figuring out the maths behind it. Language is no issue

Comment: So for x=3, b = a, b, c, a b c, b c abc, c abc bcabc, abc bcabc cabcbcabc, etc.? (Spaces for clarity, only commas separate array elements)

Comment: What @Mad Physicist wrote is correct.  Now if there is a query where p=7, q=5, my answer should be c or the 3rd character.

Comment: Hint: length of the elements is the higher-order Fibonacci sequence. You need to find first which (p-i) part is q in, that is, if q < HFib(p-x+1, x) or HFib(p-x+1, x) <= q < HFib(p-x+2, x), or so on; then you recurse.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this answer as I figured it out, so please bear with me.

As you mentioned, it is much easier to find out where the character at `b[p][q]` comes from among the original `x` characters than to generate `b[p]` for large `p`. To do so, we will use a loop to find where the current `b[p][q]` came from, thereby reducing `p` until it is between `1` and `x`, and `q` until it is `1`.

Let's look at an example for `x=3` to see if we can get a formula:

```
p  N(p)  b[p]
-  ----  ----
1  1     a
2  1     b
3  1     c
4  3     a b c
5  5     b c abc
6  9     c abc bcabc
7  17    abc bcabc cabcbcabc
8  31    bcabc cabcbcabc abcbcabccabcbcabc
9  57    cabcbcabc abcbcabccabcbcabc bcabccabcbcabcabcbcabccabcbcabc
```

The sequence is clear: `N(p) = N(p-1) + N(p-2) + N(p-3)`, where `N(p)` is the number of characters in the pth element of `b`. Given `p` and `x`, you can just brute-force compute all the `N` for the range `[1, p]`. This will allow you to figure out which prior element of `b` `b[p][q]` came from.

To illustrate, say `x=3`, `p=9` and `q=45`.

1. The chart above gives `N(6)=9`, `N(7)=17` and `N(8)=31`. Since `45>9+17`, you know that `b[9][45]` comes from `b[8][45-(9+17)] = b[8][19]`.
2. Continuing iteratively/recursively, `19>9+5`, so `b[8][19] = b[7][19-(9+5)] = b[7][5]`.
3. Now `5>N(4)` but `5<N(4)+N(5)`, so `b[7][5] = b[5][5-3] = b[5][2]`.
4. `b[5][2] = b[3][2-1] = b[3][1]`
5. Since `3 <= x`, we have our termination condition, and `b[9][45]` is `c` from `b[3]`.

Something like this can very easily be computed either recursively or iteratively given starting `p`, `q`, `x` and `b` up to `x`. My method requires `p` array elements to compute `N(p)` for the entire sequence. This can be allocated in an array or on the stack if working recursively.

Here is a reference implementation in vanilla Python (no external imports, although numpy would probably help streamline this):

```
def so38509640(b, p, q):
    """
    p, q are integers. b is a char sequence of length x.
    list, string, or tuple are all valid choices for b.
    """
    x = len(b)

    # Trivial case
    if p <= x:
        if q != 1:
            raise ValueError('q={} out of bounds for p={}'.format(q, p))
        return p, b[p - 1]

    # Construct list of counts
    N = [1] * p
    for i in range(x, p):
        N[i] = sum(N[i - x:i])
    print('N =', N)

    # Error check
    if q > N[-1]:
        raise ValueError('q={} out of bounds for p={}'.format(q, p))

    print('b[{}][{}]'.format(p, q), end='')

    # Reduce p, q until it is p < x
    while p > x:
        # Find which previous element character q comes from
        offset = 0
        for i in range(p - x - 1, p):
            if i == p - 1:
                raise ValueError('q={} out of bounds for p={}'.format(q, p))
            if offset + N[i] >= q:
                q -= offset
                p = i + 1
                print(' = b[{}][{}]'.format(p, q), end='')
                break
            offset += N[i]
    print()
    return p, b[p - 1]
```

Calling `so38509640('abc', 9, 45)` produces

```
N = [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57]
b[9][45] = b[8][19] = b[7][5] = b[5][2] = b[3][1]
(3, 'c') # <-- Final answer
```

Similarly, for the example in the question, `so38509640('abc', 7, 5)` produces the expected result:

```
N = [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17]
b[7][5] = b[5][2] = b[3][1]
(3, 'c') # <-- Final answer
```

Sorry I couldn't come up with a better function name :) This is simple enough code that it should work equally well in Py2 and 3, despite differences in the `range` function/class.

I would be very curious to see if there is a non-iterative solution for this problem. Perhaps there is a way of doing this using modular arithmetic or something...